# set column Widths for Bootstrap Responsive Table in Repeat Control

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I have a repeat control and for each row I want to set up a bootstrap responsive table. Right now it looks something like this:
[image]

the problem is that I would like to set the column widths so they line up better. I have tried to do a two row grid but the two rows collapse nicely but then the data is not under the Label. I have tried class="width:200px" or used % as well in the  div but that seems to have no impact. Like wise if added to the  of the .

I would settle for a grid or responsive table solution.
my code looks something like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table  table-bordered table-condensed " style="width:900px">
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th class="width:150px">Label</th>
            <th class="width:250px">Default Approvers</th>
            <th class="width:75px">Auto Process</th>
            <th class="width:75px">Routing</th>
            <th class="width:75px">Post Approval</th>
            <th class="with:75px">Post Denial</th>
            <th class="width:50px">Notify Late</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
.
.
.
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you used `class` attributes to set `style` values. If you change to `style` then it should work.
I recommend you to use a colgroup though. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Comment: I knew that! Some times the obvious is hidden in plain sight!